# Examples of great looking SSRS pdf reports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to make a case of using SSRS as an option for some great looking reports. Is there a place where somebody can point to? I am looking for some great looking fancy data driven reports built using SQL Server SSRS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[ReportSurfer.com](http://www.ReportSurfer.com) is also very good.

Comment: used the Halo sample. That is what I am looking for.

Comment: Site is empty for me.

Comment: Shame - it was a good resource.

Answer (score 17):

Example sites:

[Codeplex Site](http://www.codeplex.com/MSFTRSProdSamples/) Site mentioned by Cory

[Report Examples](http://blogs.msdn.com/chrisfie/archive/2008/04/10/new-sql-reporting-services-sample-reports-for-project-server.aspx) Examples by some guy.

[GotReportViewer](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/) The best sample site. Not data driven.

[Live Demo](http://richardlees.com.au/sites/Demonstrations/Documents/Web%20Dashboard%20-%20close%20to%20real%20time%20analytics%20of%20this%20internet%20site/Internet%20Activity%20Today.aspx) Very slow site, but has a live demonstration of SSRS. *Requires IE

[YouTube Demonstration](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znRJ-9CoBfw) A guy talking about AdHoc Reporting in SSRS.

[Aspose PDF Samples](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/ssrs-rendering-extensions/aspose.pdf-for-reporting-services/sample-reports-gallery.html) (Renderer Addin, however samples are all do-able without them)

[Aspose Word Samples](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/ssrs-rendering-extensions/aspose.words-for-reporting-services/sample-gallery.html) (Renderer Addin, however samples are all do-able without them)

[Nevron Charts Samples](https://www.nevron.com/products-reporting-services-chart-gallery.aspx) (Add-in, Commercial)

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the [Microsoft samples](http://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=18649) on codeplex?  Here is a screenshot of one of the reports

[alt text http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/6281/captureevm.png](http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/6281/captureevm.png)

Comment: http://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com/ works.